# Bazel fetch remote file not as a WORKSPACE rule?

Tags: bazel

In Bazel, how do I fetch a remote file as a build rule not as a WORKSPACE rule?

I want to use a build rule because WORKSPACE rules are not loaded for transitively.

e.g. this fails

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_file")

http_file(
  name = "foo",
  urls = [ "https://example.com" ],
  sha256 = "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855",
  executable = True,
)
```

> Error in repository_rule: 'repository rule http_file' can only be called during workspace loading

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that, you have to implement your own rule, a naïve trivial example relying on `curl` to fetch could be:

```
def _impl(ctx):
    args = ctx.actions.args()
    args.add("-o", ctx.outputs.out)
    args.add(ctx.attr.url)
    ctx.actions.run(
        outputs = [ctx.outputs.out],
        executable = "curl",
        arguments = [args],
    )

get_stuff = rule(
    _impl,
    attrs = {
        "url": attr.string(
            mandatory = True,
        ),
    },
    outputs = {"out": "%{name}.out"},
)
```

But (and esp. in such a trivial) for, it comes with problems. Apart from, do you want to step out of sandbox during the build? And do you want to talk to someone across the network during the build (out of the sandbox)? Bypassing `repository_cache`, and possibly getting `remote_cache` involved (networked caching of networked fetching). Specifically in this example, if content of the file pointed to by `url` changes... build has no idea and only fetches it when it either hasn't done so or the `url` itself has changed. I.e. the implementation would need to be more robust (mimic that of `http_file` for instance).

But it actually sounds like you're trying to address a different problem (transitive external dependencies, for which there could be another solution). One trick used for that is to define a macro (in your first level dependency to load define the next hop) and after declaring that first step as an external dependency in your parent project, `load` the that macro and use it from parent project `WORKSPACE`. This too has a price though, namely the first level dependency has to always be present (fetched or already cached), even if build target asked for does not actually need it (as that `load` and macro call will always pull it in).

Comment: The remote file would have an expected hash, so it's breaking the sandbox but in a controlled way.

Comment: And you can of course have a fetcher more capable or wrapping around `curl` so that you can check incoming hash digest (and also updates thereof would force the target to be "rebuilt"). I am not 100% sure this is still the solution for hinted specific problem, but... short version is: custom rule (or `genrule`, but I'd rather not) would be in order.

Comment: It's surprising this is not built in - Buck, Please, etc all have it